# What a newspaper headline is 'artifact-specific' means

Tags: meaning-in-context

> The headline feels like an artifact—specific to the story beneath it, yes, but more like an echo from an America that now seems lost. - [the Wall Street Journal 2022. 11. 9.](https://www.wsj.com/articles/all-of-nation-rallies-to-johnsons-support-kennedy-assassination-1963-september-11-national-unity-2022-midterm-partisanship-11667877426?st=qg5hs4gzc6p8f9u&reflink=desktopwebshare_permalink)

I know what 'artifact' and 'specific' each means but I can't even guess the meaning of 'artifact-specific' on a newspaper headline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Artifact-specific' is not a hyphenated word. That line is a dash, used like a semicolon to indicate the start of a new clause.

The writer means that the headline, although it is specific to the story, feels like an echo from a long past era in America.